# Counting chars from right - shell script

Tags: shell, awk, raspberry-pi

I have a temperature sensor connected to a *nix system and the typical output is something like:

```
pi@raspberrypi $ cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000202070c/w1_slave
c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 : crc=12 YES
c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 t=12187
```

The result comes without any comma, but is assumed that is always coming with 3 digits after the comma, so in this example would be 12.187º.

I have implemented a filter that places a comma after the second char, and it works most of the time:

```
grep t= | awk '{print $10;}'|  sed 's/t\=//g' | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g'
```

However, during winter, temperature drops below 10º and my filter returns values like 95,32º (when it should be 9,532º).

Is there any way of counting characters from the right, so I could always count with the 3 digital characters (and avoiding this problem in temperatures below 10º)?

Thanks,
Joaoabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can handle floating point operations:

```
awk '/t=/ { sub(/t=/,"",$NF); print $NF/1000}' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000202070c/w1_slave
```

Comment: awk can also handle opening files ;-). Lose the UUOC.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then what you want to do is :

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)$/,\1/g'
```

`$` in a regex means 'the end' so this searches for 3 digits right at the end of a string and replaces them with **comma+the found digits**.

(Note: This should be the last part of your pipe, with the beginning unchanged.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F= '/t=/ {print $NF/1000}' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000202070c/w1_slave
12.187
```

Or store it to a variable:

```
temp=$(awk -F= '/t=/ {print $NF/1000}' /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00000202070c/w1_slave)
echo "$temp"
12.187
```

Answer (score 0):

don't do `grep|awk|sed|sed...`, try this:

```
...|awk -F't=' -v OFS='t=' 'NF>1{$2=sprintf("%'\''d",$2)}7'
```

test with your data:

```
kent$  echo "c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 : crc=12 YES
c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 t=12187"|awk -F't=' -v OFS='t=' 'NF>1{$2=sprintf("%'\''d",$2)}7'
c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 : crc=12 YES
c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 t=12,187
```

awk has the format pattern in 'printf' for your requirement. just use it.

**if you just want to have the t= value**:

```
awk -F't=' -v OFS='t=' 'NF>1{printf "%'\''d\n",$2}'
```

with same input:

```
kent$  echo "c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 : crc=12 YES
c3 00 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 12 t=12187"|awk -F't=' -v OFS='t=' 'NF>1{printf "%'\''d\n",$2}'                                                                                     
12,187
```